# How to allow user to access their FB album and share an image from their album

Tags: facebook-graph-api, upload, share

I was recently asked if it were possible to allow a visitor to upload their own images from their facebook album to our site.

So the visitor would click "Upload from FB" they click it and they have to give permission for our site to access their account. They would then choose an image from their albums and essentially upload that image into our site.

Can something like this even be done?

I know I can access albums using the graph api. Are there any legal or privacy issues in doing so?

Comment: please note - 

on https://developers.facebook.com/policy/contact/
`For discussions about technical issues, please go to Facebook Stack Overflow.`

Stackoverflow is not here to answer legal answers, so don't take any answer here regarding this matter as an approval to the question at hand.

Comment: @Roni I'm almost certain I did... don't know how it got placed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code here:  https://github.com/bearlake/putafilteronit/blob/master/index.php

The code is pretty messy as I never cleaned it up but it shows how I pulled in FB albums and allowed a user to choose a picture.

Answer (score 3):

1 - From [Facebook developers policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) `section II, 2.`

> You may cache data you receive through use of the Facebook API in
>   order to improve your application’s user experience, but you should
>   try to keep the data up to date. This permission does not give you any
>   rights to such data.

**You should read this document as it provides all the legal answers regarding the platform.**

2 - On the technical side of the question, yes it can be done - there are many facebook application that lets you browse your photos and add effect to it such as [Aviary Editor](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://apps.facebook.com/aviaryeditor/&ei=55s0UfWsCtG6hAeS64CwBA&usg=AFQjCNGlUrv4ImfBLe-CkCSdFZUrGpOy0Q&sig2=Tld4hXL3V49d-TNj7-4W6w&bvm=bv.43148975,d.ZG4)